# How to transfer money from an ATM card in a village in India without an ATM machine or smart phone?

Tags: india, atm

Is there any way to transfer money from one account to another account using only an ATM card? We don't have a card swiping machine or the Bhim app.
I have a shop in a village where ATM and card swiping machines are not available. I want to take money from a customer who only has an ATM card.

So how can I transfer money from his ATM card to my account ?

Comment: Can a customer use a credit card or debit card in your shop?

Comment: It would help to know what kind of ATM card, visa/mastercard/express/somethine else.

Comment: @LifeInTheTrees None of those cards you listed are considered "ATM cards" by almost anyone. Those are Credit Cards.

Answer (score 1):

> So how can I transfer money from his ATM card to my account ?

Some bank's ATM allow you to transfer the money from ATM card to bank account using at ATM Machine.

So if there is no ATM, you can't transfer money with just ATM card.

Comment: Question is I want to take money from a customer who only has an ATM card.

Answer (score -1):

This is answer is based on some condition.As a Shop owner you have a mobile with Internet connectivity.There is an app named as 'Phonepe'.There is many option to transfer through ATM to your bank account.

I think instead of own POS its good idea for village shop.

Comment: This is incorrect. Phonepay is an Iran based private company not operating in India. There is PhonePe in India; it is a digital wallet. So the customer should have a smart phone and Debit card to transfer money to merchant.

Comment: Sorry,I just correct that

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try using PayTM? You could definitely get money from your customer's PayTM account. Just sign up for PayTM using your mobile. Then ask your customer to transfer money from her payTM account. Later you could withdraw this money to your bank account.

Comment: The customer does not have smartphone or internet to use PayTm. Else he would have used BHIM